# IIS Access for Visual Studio Asp.Net Application

Tags: asp.net, iis, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to gain access to a Microsoft Word document at a network location via a button click in my application.  The code is as follows:

```
 Protected Sub Button3Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        Dim path3 As String = "full file path here"
        Dim wordApp As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application
        Dim wordDoc As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document
        wordApp.Visible = True
        wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(path3)
 End Sub
```

I am running this on IIS8, with the application pool of my site as DefaultAppPool, and the identity as ApplicationPoolIdentity.  My understanding is that what I need to do is give DefaultAppPool read permissions to the file in question.  I have given access to the user groups IIS_IUSRS and IUSR.  Since I am using forms authentication, if I have access with IIS_IUSRS, then I should be able to access the file, yet I am not able to. I believe I have to give access to IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool to the file I need, however, the file is located on a different server than the website, so it is not a group/user name available to give to the file.  Is there any work around to solve this problem?

Comment: What do you think `wordApp.Visible = True : wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(path3)` does when ran from a web server? It most certainly won't open Word on the machine of the visitor of that web site. If that isn't what you expect to happen, explain what you mean by _"I am not able to"_. What _do_ you expect to happen, and what _does_ happen?

Comment: @CodeCaster I expect it to open Word on the client that's using the website.  Is that not what it will do?  Right now the button click just redirects me to my log in page, as expected, because I do not have access to the file it is trying to access.

Comment: That code runs on the server. It won't open Word on the client machine.

Comment: Ah.  Well then, that's certainly not what I want it to do.  Is there a way to open the document on the client machine?  Off the top of my head, my first instinct is to put a script block in the .aspx page with a function that opens the document in MSWord, then calling that function as the OnClientClick property of the button.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

If both servers are domain joined, then you can run your application as a user in the domain (account created for the purposes of running your site).  Then grant access on the remote file to the user (newly created account) in question.

Comment: I am unsure what you mean by domain joined.  Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: Are both the web server and file server joined to Active Directory?

Comment: I'm still unsure of what you mean, but they are two separate machines that are on the same network, so I'm tempted to say no.